# Delay with touchBegan Cocos2d iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am attempting to make it so in  my CCScene, if a user taps to shoot a projectile there's a delay at the end of the bullet shot from allowing them to shoot another, maybe 2 seconds.

I've attempted this:

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CCSprite *arrow = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
    arrow.position = player.position;
    [self addChild:arrow];


    CCActionMoveTo *actionStart = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.3f position:targetPosition];
    CCActionRemove *actionEnd = [CCActionRemove action];
    CCActionDelay *delay = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:2.0];

    [arrow runAction:[CCActionSequence actions: actionStart, actionEnd, delay, nil]];
}
```

but I am still able to repeatedly click to fire projectiles with no delay. Any ideas how I could fix this, and more importantly what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating a new arrow each time? You can instead just do this:

Create an arrow property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCSprite* arrow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCSprite* player;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint targetPosition;
```

Create the arrow sprite:

```
- (void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    self.player = ...
    self.targetPosition = ...

    self.arrow = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
    self.arrow.position = self.player.position;
    self.arrow.visible = FALSE;
    [self addChild:self.arrow];
}
```

Then in touches began:

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.arrow.numberOfRunningActions)
    {
        CCActionMoveTo* move = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.3f
                                                         position:self.targetPosition];

        CCActionShow* show = [CCActionShow action];
        CCActionRemove* hide = [CCActionHide action];
        CCActionDelay* delay = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:2.0];
        CCActionSequence* seq = [CCActionSequence actions:show, move, hide, delay, nil];

        [self.arrow runAction:seq];
    }
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Helped great thanks, just had to add in another action to simply reset the positioning of the arrow, I simply did this by [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:0 position:self.player.position]; right before the delay in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the action you applied applies to your arrow `CCSprite`.

This means that the delay is in effect but on the `arrow` sprite that you created before, effectively having no effect.

I think for this use case you might just have a `NSDate` property called something like `lastShootingTime` and in `touchBegan` test the time and if the `timeElapsedSinceNow` is larger than what you want start the new action sequence and reset the `lastShootingTime`.